# slider callback with bokeh and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am using a slider to show some words. All the lists are fine. I have more than 20 elements with all of them. The slider worked with Bokeh **0.12.6** but now some elements do not show up at all with **0.12.9**. The weird thing is this does not seem to be random every time I run the code. For example element 6 does not show up every time but exists in the list. 
I am using the value of the slider to change the hbar and the texts in the same time.
Anybody with the same issue? Did I make a mistake in the callback function?

```
sourcesl = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(ysl=ysl, rightsl=rightsl, hightsl=hightsl, leftsl=leftsl, thertpctn0=thertpctn0, thertpct0=thertpct0, wlen=wlen, wtext=wtext, thepct=thepct, prtg=prtg))
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=sourcesl), code="""
            var data = source.data;
            var w = cb_obj.value

            rightsl = data['rightsl']
            prtg = data['prtg']
            wtext = data['wtext']
            ysl = data['ysl']            
            thertpctn0 = data['thertpctn0']
            thertpct0 = data['thertpct0']
            wlen = data['wlen']                
            thepct = data['thepct']           

            var som = 0
            for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                som = som +thertpctn0[i]
            }
            rightsl[0] = 100*(som/wlen[0])
            rightsl[1] = 100                
            wtext[0] = thertpct0[w] 
            prtg[0] = thepct[w]

            source.change.emit();
        """)
        slider = Slider(start=1, end=20, value=20, step=1, title="SLIDER for Words Most Used")
        slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
psl = figure(width=355, height=200,tools="pan,reset,previewsave")
        psl.y_range = Range1d(0,4)
        psl.x_range = Range1d(0, 100)
        psl.hbar('ysl', 'hightsl','rightsl', 'leftsl',  color="LightSeaGreen", source=sourcesl)
psl.text(45, 3, text='wtext',
                alpha=0.6667, text_font_size='32pt', text_baseline='middle',
                text_align='center', source=sourcesl)
        nby = 2
        psl.text(45, nby, text='prtg',
                 alpha=1, text_font_size='12pt', text_baseline='middle',
                 text_align='center', source=sourcesl)
        tex = ['\u0025']
        sourcespct = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(tex=tex))
        psl.text(54, nby, text='tex',
                 alpha=0.6667, text_font_size='12pt', text_baseline='middle',
                 text_align='center', source=sourcespct)
```

[image]
[image]

***UPDATED***Finally the code to test: some elements like 6(?) do not display
Here is the code to test with fake data:

```
    def test100():
    from bokeh.models import Slider, Range1d

    psl = figure(width=355, height=150, tools="pan,reset,previewsave")

    ysl = [1,2]
    hightsl = [0.5, 0.1]
    leftsl = [0, 0]
    thertpctn0 = [0]
    thertpctn = []
    for i in range(1, 21):
        thertpctn.append(i*.1)
    thertpctn0.extend(thertpctn)

    somme = sum(thertpctn)
    ratio = 100 * (somme / 20)
    rightsl = [ratio, 0]
    thertpct0= ["0"]
    thertpct = []
    for i in range(1, 21):
        j = "{}abcd".format(str(i))
        thertpct.append(j)
    thertpct0.extend(thertpct)
    wlen = [20]
    wtext = [thertpct0[-1]]
    # for i in range(0, 20):
    #     j = "{}abcdefghij".format(str(i))
    #     wtext.append(j)
    thepct = []
    prtg = []

    sourcesl = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(ysl=ysl, rightsl=rightsl, hightsl=hightsl, leftsl=leftsl, thertpctn0=thertpctn0,
            thertpct0=thertpct0, wlen=wlen, wtext=wtext)) #, thepct=thepct, prtg=prtg))

    callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=sourcesl), code="""
                    var data = source.data;
                    var w = cb_obj.value

                    rightsl = data['rightsl']

                    wtext = data['wtext']
                    ysl = data['ysl']            
                    thertpctn0 = data['thertpctn0']
                    thertpct0 = data['thertpct0']
                    wlen = data['wlen']                


                    var som = 0
                    for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                        som = som +thertpctn0[i]
                    }
                    rightsl[0] = 100*(som/wlen[0])
                    rightsl[1] = 100                
                    wtext[0] = thertpct0[w] 


                    source.change.emit();
                """) # prtg[0] = thepct[w] thepct = data['thepct'] prtg = data['prtg']

    slider = Slider(start=1, end=20, value=20, step=1, title="SLIDER for Words Most Used")
    slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

    psl.y_range = Range1d(0, 4)
    psl.x_range = Range1d(0, 100)
    psl.hbar('ysl', 'hightsl', 'rightsl', 'leftsl', color="LightSeaGreen", source=sourcesl)

    psl.text(45, 3, text='wtext',
                 alpha=0.6667, text_font_size='32pt', text_baseline='middle',
                 text_align='center', source=sourcesl)
    # nby = 2
    # psl.text(45, nby, text='prtg',
    #              alpha=1, text_font_size='12pt', text_baseline='middle',
    #              text_align='center', source=sourcesl)

    # tex = ['\u0025']
    # sourcespct = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(tex=tex))
    # psl.text(54, nby, text='tex',
    #          alpha=0.6667, text_font_size='12pt', text_baseline='middle',
    #          text_align='center', source=sourcespct)
    wdgsld = WidgetBox(slider)
    ltest = column([wdgsld, psl])
    show(ltest)
```

Comment: If you complete this code (i.e. with missing imports and any (fake) data needed) then I could run it and try to investigate

Comment: I will work on this today and hopefully have a code replicating this issue today or tomorrow. tx

Comment: There are still several missing imports and a formatting error (starts with errant `def`) but after fixing those and testing with `master` it seems to be working as best I can tell. Can you try your code with `0.12.10dev2`?

Comment: Sorry some imports were out of the function, I should have added there. Could you tell how to get the 0.12.10dev2? I tried the anaconda command but I got 0.12.9 which was the last release.

Comment: Instructions are here: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/installation.html#developer-builds

Comment: Now i get:   Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /bokeh/channel/dev/simple/bokeh/

Comment: That's some local network problem on your end, those messages are not coming from Bokeh

Comment: yes 0.12.10 did it. Thank you

Comment: BUT there is other old issue with the slider when you have a lot of element. Will post the code in git.